# Function that manipulates collection and return the same type

Tags: python

I was just wondering this while programming in python. If I have a function `foo` which take a collection (list or tuple, perhaps set etc.) and manipulates on its elements somehow, e.g. filter, trim, increases, etc. should such function return the same type? For instance, if it accepts any collection and filter things out, what should it return as an output object? Is it important at all?

There are also other containers, like `numpy`. So I have a `numpy` object `a`. There might be operations I cannot do on `a` using methods from `numpy` and therefore have to convert it to a list. Should I check for a type and return the same type?

If yes, is there a general technique to check type and return the same one?

Comment: Your question would be a better one if you had a concrete example of what you're talking about (and not a FooBar one either).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't generally possible to return a new collection, because you don't know what the constructor expects. I.e. `type(original)(new_values)` may or may not work.

Instead, you should use the most general collection Python knows: an iterable. In particular, this allows you to conveniently use **generators**.

Compare this function returning a list …

```
def only_positive(items):
  out = []
  for x in items:
    if x > 0:
      out.append(x)
  return x
```

… with a generator-based function:

```
def only_positive(items):
  for x in items:
    if y > 0:
      yield x
```

Note that many builtins that previously operated on lists where changed to generator function in Python 3. E.g. for Py2, `filter()` is documented to return:

> If sequence is a tuple or string, return the same type, else return a list.

But in Py3, `filter()` is actually an iterator object.

Numpy takes a different approach because the whole point is performing operations on a whole array. Typically, these functions either

- take and return a single scalar value where the computation is performed as for a single-element array, or
- take an ndarray or an array-like object that can be coerced to an ndarray, and return an ndarray.

The input type is not generally preserved.

Comment: So if I want to return the most general collection in Python, iterable, shall I define something in a function like a class with required methods like __iter__, __next__, etc? Sorry hopefully you understand if my question is too trivial and answer is obvious. It is still not clear enough for me :/

Comment: @Celdor that's one way, but generator functions are _much_ easier. Just `yield` some value when it's ready, and let the caller worry about whether they need to store it in some data structure and what that data structure would be. E.g.: `result = list(your_function(1, 2, 3))`

Answer (score 2):

There are generally two kinds of collection frameworks: those without duplicate code but losing the collection type, and those which preserve the collection type but have duplicated code.

Most fall into the first camp, e.g. in .NET, everything returns `IEnumerable`, in Ruby, everything returns `Array`, in Python, everything returns an iterable, etc. Smalltalk falls into the second camp: all operations preserve the type, but at the cost of simply duplicating the operations for every type.

Scala has the first large-scale collections library I know of that manages to be type-preserving without duplication. The key idea is the concept of *builders*, which are objects that know how to (efficiently) build collections of a specific type. So, an operation like `filter` only needs to look up the builder for the collection type and then it can use this builder to efficiently build the result collection without actually having to know about each and every collection there could ever be. In Scala, it is the type system (or more precisely *implicit resolution*) that takes care of this lookup *at compile time* (so that there is no runtime overhead), but it can just as well be done at runtime.

Note, however, that type-preserving collection operations may have surprising consequences. For example, you don't expect `map` to change the length of a collection, but

```
map(Set(1, 2, 3, 4), lambda el: is_even(el)) == Set(true, false)
```

Also, in some cases, you actually have to return a more general type, or another related type. E.g., a `ByteSet` can only contain the numbers 1-255, so

```
map(ByteSet(16), lambda el: el.__str__()) == Set("16")
map(ByteSet(16), lambda el: el ** 2) == IntSet(256)
```

So, if you want to build a type-preserving collections framework, you can look at Scala's collections framework and its *builders* and the `CanBuildFrom` implicit type-level machinery. I would suggest you look at the strawman proposal for the simplified and redesigned framework in Scala 2.13 instead of the current release since the latter one is considered to be overengineered and overly complex.